# SSAS Actions are not showing in pivot tables in Additional Actions

Tags: ssas, mdx

We're seeing some very strange behavior with our SSAS Actions. We have a cube with two Actions (named "A Detail" and "B Detail") where they both have conditions on Measure M. Both are Target Type Cells, Rowset Types.

When we use a pivot table in Excel and go to Additional Actions, we only see one of them, usually the first one in alphabetical order (A Detail). Strangely, if we rename the Action name of "A Detail" to "zA Detail", then we see "B Detail" but not "zA Detail", presumably because of the alphabetical ordering.

We are using ASSP - Analysis Services Stored Procedure Project for some of our Action logic..`(SELECT ("+ ASSP.CurrentCellAttributes() + ") ON 0 FROM [Opportunities])` although I don't think this is affecting anything.

I'm not sure how best to troubleshoot this or break this down further. I had no idea one Action could affect the visibility of other Actions.

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) / Excel 2016

Comment: I'm not sure what assp is.

Comment: @whytheq Analysis Services Stored Procedure Project - https://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/

Comment: I posted this on the ASSP forum so other ASSP developers would be aware and could provide their thoughts. I haven't seen this before! Strange. Does seem unrelated to ASSP but you never know. Have you tried this with hardcoded actions which don't leverage ASSP? Do you have any Perspectives and are both actions in the Perspective? https://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/discussions/655440